# Querystring values not passed from HTTPS to WCF service hosted on HTTP

Tags: javascript, c#, wcf

Background:  We have two subdomains; one, public facing has SSL, the other is non-SSL.  The private subdomain hosts a simple WCF service - one method with two parameters.  I have a self-contained Javascript file which is included in any page and writes out a form and submits, using `GET` method, to the service via `XMLHttpRequest`.

I would like to be able to call the service from the SSL subdomain using the CORS (cross origin resource sharing) approach. I have got cross domain requests to the service working from another non-SSL host.

However, when I include the script on the HTTPS server and submit the form, the service method gets called, but no values are passed, even though they are definitely set in the Javascript.

Does anyone know why this would be?  And if there is a solution.

We don't want to host the service on the public subdomain, and we don't need SSL on the private subdomain.

I'm guessing it will be something to do with SSL and encryption, or there is some configuration setting I'm missing.

If required I can show my `web.config` and Javascript file.

**Edit 20150209**

For information, I have tried hosting the service and Javascript file on the https server and can call the service successfully from another non-ssl domain.  However, we don't really want the service on the public domain.